# Passing data from Activity to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an `BroadcastReceiver` which add prefix to phone number of outgoing call and prefix is add by user.

Are there any way to pass Prefix (String variable) to `BroadcastReceiver`?

I mean after my app is kill, this `BroadcastReceiver` still working with Prefix that user wanted to add.

This is my code for register `BroadcastReceiver`

```
PackageManager pm  = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new componentName(MyActivity.this,MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Through intent you can do like this -

Passing Class -

```
Intent i = new Intent(passing.this, received.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("keyvalue", "yourprefixvalue");
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

Received Class -

In your broadcast receiver class contains `onReceive` method and having arguments intent. So that it can be used to get the result value from bundle.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String result = intent.getString("keyvalue");
    // your method
}
```

Try this out. I've passed some values to my `BroadcastReceiver` class like this.

Comment: Thanks for your clearly answer. But, i still have problem that i not start my broadcast receiver as an Activity. I used `PackageManager` for enable it. This will work even my app was killed.

Comment: Oops sorry dude. I didn't work with that. So that i don't know anything. Anyway +1 for nice concept.

Answer (score 3):

By using Intent, we can passing the data from activity to broadcast receiver.

```
intent.getExtras().get("testString");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("keyvalue",getmessage);
```

// getmessage is string value

in pending intent you have to use below line-
          PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

In broadcastreceiver

```
 String message = context.getStringExtra("keyvalue");
```

Using this i passing the data from activity to broadcast receiver.

Hope this helpful

Answer (score 2):

Through intent u can pass the string value to the broadcast reciever

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem, I register my broadcastreceiver in mainfest file, but don't know how to pass pre-fix number to my broadcast receiver. Anybody know how to do it?